# Windows Server 2012 Task is not working. Batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, backup, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I am trying to setup a Task in my server that is running Windows Server 2012. The task's action is to execute a batch file, which backs up all my mysql databases. The task is set to run every 1 minute for 1 day, like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, the script runs once, and it doesn't execute again. I can tell, because in the Status Column in the Task Scheduler window it says running, but it does not either create or override the old mysql dumps.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers.

---

NOTE:

The database size is roughly 10Mb, therefore I am 100% sure that I am not running with any performance issues.

Comment: Try giving it a larger gap between executions! Backup the database every minute for a day sound a bit crazy anyway.

Comment: Could you please change the question title to something more specific than "not working"? and please share the batch file!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry for not being specific, but the size of the database is roughly 10 Mb, therefore the operation size can be ignored in this case.

Comment: Are you sure when it runs the first time that it's completing? It sounds to me like it's falling over and leaving a permanent status of "Running", therefore, it's not going to execute again, because as far as Windows Scheduler is concerned it's still active. Impossible to say for certain without seeing your batch file.

Comment: Good hint. It helped me solve my issue. At the end it was something related to the batch file I was using, not the task itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it was an issue related to the batch file I was using. I needed to run the program with administrator privileges. This made the batch script be on hold (status as "running") when trying to 7-zip my files, hence not finalizing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Task can be done within a minute because same task can't run again will old is already running. So that you have to adjust the time for repeating.